# Finding point with the help of automorphism $\sigma$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Assume we have a field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt A,\sqrt[3]{B},\xi_3)$, $\xi_3^3=1$ and $\xi_3\neq 1$. Now, consider the map $\sigma_K : \sqrt[3]{B} \to \xi_3\sqrt[3]{B}$ that fixes other generators of $K$. Moreover, it fixes subfield $\mathbb Q(\sqrt A,\xi_3)$.

Here I choose $P=(\sqrt[3]{B},\sqrt A t^3)$. Okay, now I define $P^\sigma$ as image of $P$ under $\sigma$. By using this definition, look at this sum $P+ P^{\sigma_K}+ P^{\sigma^2_K}=0$. But I could not figure out why this sum is equal to $0$.

Btw, I thought that we choose a point actually this is a pair so I will apply $\sigma$ componentwise. So, I wrote something like the following, $P^{\sigma_K}=(\xi_3^2 \sqrt[3]{B},\sqrt A t^3)$ and what about $P^{\sigma^2_K}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $\xi_3$ satisfies $X^3-1$ but not $X-1$, so it satisfies $\frac{X^3-1}{X-1} = X^2+X+1$

Comment: so what? I guess it doesnt help me